# How to search arabic data with english language

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I am new in php and working on site that require to store data either in english or arabic language. I successfully store arabic data in mysql but the problem is that how to search the data that are in arabic with english language.

can anyone help me how to do it or what's the most efficient way and better way to store in db?

Comment: Can you please explain how do you want to search Arabic data with English language with some examples?

Comment: Do you mean transliteration?

Comment: @-Mahmoud Gamal that's what i want to know if its possible in case no than which way is efficient or better to accomplish it... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use UTF8 encoding to keep your whole site and database "multilingual". In such case there's basically no difference if you are searching for English or Arabic strings, because technically you just look for UTF8 string. And UTF8 will cover Arabic as well as English